# How to delete records with default value SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to delete records with a default value? I tried to delete using 'as default' and '= default' but this doesn't work. Is there a way for this?

My code:

```
delete from Address
where District = default

delete from Address
where District as default
```

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.
```

Comment: What about rows that are assigned the "default" value explicitly?

Comment: What about rows that are assigned before the default was changed?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It doesn't have matter

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just want to know if there is a way for this

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the default value for the column:

```
SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName AND
      TABLE_NAME = 'Address' AND
      COLUMN_NAME = 'District'
```

And then incorporate this into a query.  You can also do that directly, but it becomes a little tricky because the types might not match.

But, if `distinct` is a string, you can use:

```
delete from Address
where District = (select default_value
                  from information_schema.columns
                  where table_schema = @table_schema and
                        table_name = 'Address' and
                        column_name = 'District'
                 );
```

Important caveat:  This deletes any row where the value *matches* the default value, even if that value were explicitly assigned to the column.

And, if the default value is `NULL` then slightly different comparisons are needed.

Comment: There can be a column with `default null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table dbo.testabc
(
    id int identity primary key clustered,
    colA varchar(100) default('abc'),
    colB int default(123456),
    colC date default(getdate())
);

insert into dbo.testabc(colA, colB, colC)
values ('xyz', 123, '20200402'),
(default, 1, '20200220'),('efd', default, '20200320'),('bcd', 100, default);
go


declare @t table(colAdef sql_variant, colBdef sql_variant, colCdef sql_variant);

begin transaction
update top (1) dbo.testabc
set colA = default,
    colB = default,
    colC = default
output inserted.colA, inserted.colB, inserted.colC into @t(colAdef, colBdef, colCdef)
rollback transaction

select 'default values', *
from @t;

select *
from dbo.testabc as a
where exists(select * from @t as t where t.colAdef = a.colA)
or exists(select * from @t as t where t.colBdef = a.colB)
or exists(select * from @t as t where t.colCdef = a.colC)
go

--cleanup
drop table dbo.testabc;
go
```